Routing traffic to a local LAN address when reachable, otherwise using WireGuard VPN
I have a WireGuard VPN set up that uses the 10.20.30.0/24 IP range. I want to configure routing on my laptop so that traffic to 10.20.30.xy is routed through 192.168.99.xy whenever the latter is reachable on the local network. If the local address isn’t reachable, I want the traffic to be routed through the WireGuard tunnel as usual.
I understand that I can get about 80% of the way there by using a script triggered by NetworkManager whenever I connect to the local network. The script would simply add the necessary routes using:
Is there a simple way to handle this automatically, accounting for local network reachability? I’m also wondering if there might be a solution using OSPF or another dynamic routing protocol that could automatically detect reachability and adjust the routing accordingly.
EDIT: I am not opposed to making a /32 route for each of my devices (there aren't that many of them). I can also adjust my network topology - making a new prefix for switched devices would definitely be an option for me.


Is there a simple way to handle this automatically, accounting for local network reachability?

I think this is probably the closest you can get with your current network layout.
The main problem is that the subnet in question is directly assigned to the wg0 interface on your laptop, and external routes generally have lower priority than the automatic "local subnet" route. So part of your NM script will have to bring wg0 down when local, bring it back up when elsewhere.
Dynamic routing protocols will not help much for the same reason – e.g. if the OSPF daemon is configured to run on both eth0 and wg0 interfaces (so that it would provide routes to faraway subnets), it will always see 10.20.30.0/24 as a local network on wg0.
To make this work properly, you should change the WireGuard tunnel to not be the VPN subnet in itself, but instead to act strictly as a point-to-point link (e.g. a /30) through which the actual 10.20.30.0/24 subnet is reached, e.g. your laptop would be 10.20.255.2/30 with a static route "10.20.30.0/24 via 10.20.255.1".
This would then let you use OSPF (however, you probably still want to have OSPF on eth0 toggled by NetworkManager so as to not spam other people's Wi-Fi with frequent HELLO packets), but it would also let you use a simpler approach of having your local LAN's DHCP provide the direct route.
It is possible to deploy custom routes via DHCP option 121 (or option 249 for WinXP) – though you would still have to carefully choose the metric of the "via wg0" route to be sufficiently high (i.e. so that it would always be higher-metric and thus lower-priority than the route learned from DHCP). For example:

$ dhcpclassless @192.168.99.1 10.20.30.0/24@192.168.99.123
Routes:
    0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.99.1
    10.20.30.0/24 via 192.168.99.123

Option code: 121 (standard), 249 (MS pre-standard)
Option data: 0x00C0A86301180A141EC0A8637B

Mikrotik RouterOS:
/ip dhcp-server option
add name=classless code=121 value=0x00C0A86301180A141EC0A8637B
add name=ms-classless code=249 value=0x00C0A86301180A141EC0A8637B

ISC DHCP (old):
option option-121 0:c0:a8:63:1:18:a:14:1e:c0:a8:63:7b;

With this configuration, your laptop would learn "10.20.30.0/24 via 192.168.99.123 metric 600" (for example) from DHCP when it's local, but would fall back to the statically defined "10.20.30.0/24 via 10.20.255.1 metric 9999" when roaming.

Thanks for the answer! When I just do ip route add 10.20.30.2 via 192.168.99.2 dev wlp0s20f3, the routing works (almost) as expected - the traffic does not go through the VPN server at all. Using DHCP is an interesting option, but it does not account for reachability, right?

That works because a route for a longer prefix always has priority over a shorter one, regardless of other criteria (i.e. your /32 route gets priority over any /24 routes); it will be different when both routes are for the same /24. Admittedly you could rely on this by setting up two /25 routes, but that's a bit ugly. No, DHCP cannot account for reachability – but it might be easiest to assume that the gateway is always up (or get a dedicated gateway that can be always up), so it will always be reachable as long as you're on your home network.

I see. It wouldn't be a problem for me to make a /32 route for every device that I want to handle this way. The automatic handling of this based on network reachability is more important for me.
